# How To Upload An Array of State to an Array in Firestore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload an array of state to an array in firestore however it is yielding in an error
"Function.FieldValue.arrayUnion() requires at least one argument, but was called with 0 arguments"

```
const dbh = firebase.firestore();
this.state = {
playerID: [1,2,3]
}

var finalList = this.state.playerID
    dbh.collection("Groups").doc(this.state.group)
    .collection('Enrolled').doc('ids').set({
        players: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...finalList)
    })
```

any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error is saying that your variable _finalList_ wasn't recognized or you didn't pass any arguments into _arrayUnion()_. See https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/fieldvalue#arrayUnion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made a spelling mistake:

```
var finalList = this.state.players
```

should be:

```
var finalList = this.state.playerID
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake here as I was simplifying the code. However, that is not the issue, i have just checked to make sure that I do not have any spelling mistakes

Comment: ok it seems like whatever you are passing as the arrayUnion argument is undefined, what happens when you console.log finalList?